Как поменять шрифт в cmd програмно python?
Мне нужно, чтобы при запуске программы python сменился шрифт в консоли перед выводом print. Есть идея сделать через os.system(""), но я не знаю команды, а поиск его не увенчался успехом, поскольку за решение проблемы выдают только сменить через свойства.

Никак. Напиши свою консоль. Там делов на 10 строчек

Если вам нужен изменяемый шрифт - скорее всего вам уже нужно оконное приложение.

Тогда надо ломать голову над тем, чтобы добавить остальные используемые функции из оригинальной консоли ради одной команды. Хотя это вроде рабочая идея, если вспомнить как сделан Дварф Фортресс. Но разве нету никаких команд для всего того, что можно сделать в графическом интерфейсе?
